# Android - what library used to make daily rewards in pokerist

Tags: android

I plane to make a game like [pokerist](http://pokerist.com/en/) , First thing I face the daily reward spinner , What library should I use to make this one

I find this library 
https://github.com/avast/android-styled-dialogs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use one of this libs

https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel

https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu

https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView

I am not sure about last one but try
https://github.com/sephiroth74/AndroidWheel

hope this work with you